# List MySQL database connections

Tags: mysql, web

Does anybody know how can I find a list of all users on all web servers who are using a Database connection?

I tried to search through mysql and also through writing stored procedure , but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

use `show processlist;` on the MySQL server.